# Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to recipients in Account Settings

Tags: mailgun

What does the following Mailgun error response mean when one tries to send a message?

> Status: 400
>
> Body:   {"message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings."}

Comment: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258

Comment: Not including CC and BCC in these authorised recipients will give the same message

Answer (score 41):

Have you set up some [authorized recipients](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258) for the sandbox domain?

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account

> A sandbox subdomain of mailgun.org. Example: sandboxXX.mailgun.org.
>   This option allows for quick testing, without having to setup DNS
>   entries. This domain is provisioned automatically with every new
>   account. But you can send only to authorized recipients.

Answer (score 31):

in 2019 is:

Click to your domain, and you see at the right the Authorized Recepients box

[image]

Comment: Where do we choose our own domain?

Answer (score 4):

i have faced this problems.

if testing with sandbox, should be add the `authorized recipients`.
then copy the sandbox name as a domain.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem I solved this by doing below steps.

1. Add an email to `Authorized Recipients` - [Steps](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258).
2. When you add `from` and `to` emails **Don't add Quotation marks**

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your Mailgun account, go to the log section. There you should see a log entry for the failed attempt to delivery that email.  Click on it to see all details. it should display the full error message as well as additional information.

However, most likely you forgot to add that specific email address to the list of authorized email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

**Side note**: after adding yourself to `authorized recipients`, you also need to verify your email address. I almost disregarded the following email as commercial, but in fact I kept getting the error until I agreed:

> Hi there,
>
> Mailgun account "[...]" provided your address to test their integration with Mailgun.
>
> Please click the link below if you agree to receive emails from their account.

Answer (score 0):

There are several step for the solution for the problem:
1.First, log in to the Mailgun Control Panel (if you have not already done so).
Then, within the left-hand navigation pane, click the Sending option to expand its list of suboptions.
2.Next, click the Domains suboption.
3.Ensure that the domain in question (the sandbox domain, which is a long domain name starting with "sand") is displayed within the Domain drop-down list towards the upper-right portion of the page.

4.On the right-hand side of the page, you may enter a new or view/remove an existing Authorized Recipient.